# Ubuntu touch can't boot

Tags: kernel, ubuntu-touch

I'm in the end step of booting, see this :

```
[    7.433841,1] initrd: mounting /dev/disk/by-partlabel/boot as /root/android//boot
[    7.454993,3] initrd: checking mount label recovery
[    7.457615,0] initrd: mounting /dev/disk/by-partlabel/recovery as /root/android//recovery
[    7.497315,3] initrd: checking mount label mmc_host*
[    7.517051,2] initrd: checking mount label usb1
[    7.554915,0] initrd: checking mount label zram0
[    7.558913,1] initrd: mounting /dev/zram0 as /root/android/none
[    7.563701,1] initrd: mounting /root/var/lib/lxc/android/system.img as /root/android/system
[    7.631982,1] systemd-udevd[181]: Validate module index
```

At this point the system try to mount system.img (the android system)
But after that the system crash

```
[    7.998344,1] Crash partition in use!
[    8.998513,1] wcnss crash shutdown 0
[    8.998592,1] Rebooting in 5 seconds..
[   13.998672,1] Going down for restart now
[   13.999581,1] failed to disable wdog debug: -4
[   13.999672,1] Calling SCM to disable SPMI PMIC arbiter
```

PREV Linux version 3.4.42-g832c593-dirty (walidham@phablet)

(gcc version 4.8 (GCC) ) #5 SMP PREEMPT Thu Feb 2 21:02:43 UTC 2017

you can find full log [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-F-xs4jYP12dWdsWGFXYlpIeEU/view?usp=sharing).

please if any one have any idea about this pb tell me.

Comment: I have formatted your post to help make it more readable.
It might be worth copying he log to a text file and linking to that instead of just placing the raw file of google drive.